# Placement of segmented bar

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, accessibility, human-interface-guideline

I have a case where in one view I have two switching options: "Group by" and "View as". To increase visibility, instead of a dropdown I used **two segmented bars**, one placed on the left and the other on the right side.

Now, I need to reuse this segmented bar pattern in another place in the interface. However, as in this case there is **just one set of options**, I have placed it in the centre.

My questions is: should I leave it in the centre or should I put in any of the corners?

PFA
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should keep it on the left position. It would be coherent for the user that the left side is dedicated to toggle the group he wants to see, regardless if the UI has one or two segment bars.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in general it is ok to do it like this – distribute all the selectors from the left edge to the right edge, and place it either in the middle or on the left if there is just one.

However, in this case, the label next to this selector reads "**Group by**", which is the same as in the previous screen. So, for the sake of **internal coherence** between the screens I would err on a side of keeping it left-aligned.

How important it is, though, depends on what the other screens are. Should the selectors on them be always different (e.g. Group by only appears in two screens, and the other ones sport a different set of them) then preserving this coherence may be impossible.